# Android: Change vertical position of superscript when using SuperscriptSpan

Tags: android, spannablestring

In my app, i am trying to use `SuperscriptSpan`to show a dot. But i want to change the margin of this dot with respect to the top, ideally 0. This is how the result looks like.

I would like the dot to align with the top of the textView, while right now it is somewhere in the middle.

[image]

This is my code:

```
    SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder("MyText.");
    cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 6, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the default behavior of `SuperscriptSpan`, you'll have to create your own custom subclass of it and override both [`updateDrawState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SubscriptSpan.html#updateDrawState(android.text.TextPaint)) and [`updateMeasureState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SubscriptSpan.html#updateMeasureState(android.text.TextPaint)).

You can look at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/SuperscriptSpan.java#78) for `SuperscriptSpan` to see how they're currently implemented. Something like this will push the dot higher than you see now:

```
@Override
public void updateDrawState(@NonNull TextPaint textPaint) {
    textPaint.baselineShift += (int) ((2 * textPaint.ascent()) / 3);
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(@NonNull TextPaint textPaint) {
    textPaint.baselineShift += (int) ((2 * textPaint.ascent()) / 3);
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot!